# Batch script to merge lines from two files into a third file

Tags: file, batch-file, merge

Contents of file `A1`:

```
AA
VV
BB
```

Contents of file `A2`:

```
DD
EE
FF
```

I want to merge the contents of `A1` and `A2` as below into `A3`, so that the expected data in `A3` is:

```
AADD
VVEE
BBFF
```

Alternatively, the expected output in `A3` may be:

```
AA is from DD
VV is from EE
BB is from FF
```

Thanks for the help. I did try and search before I posted and could not find someone that has already posted something similar...

Comment: This is not "copying multiple files into one". It's "merging lines from two files into a third file".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can load the contents of the files into Batch variable arrays so each of its lines can be directly accessed in any way you wish:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Load first file into A1 array:
set i=0
for /F "delims=" %%a in (A1.txt) do (
    set /A i+=1
    set A1[!i!]=%%a
)

rem Load second file into A2 array:
set i=0
for /F "delims=" %%a in (A2.txt) do (
    set /A i+=1
    set A2[!i!]=%%a
)

rem At this point, the number of lines is in %i% variable

rem Merge data from both files and create the third one:
for /L %%i in (1,1,%i%) do echo !A1[%%i]! is from !A2[%%i]!>> A3.txt
```

**EDIT** *Alternative solution*

There is another way to do it that don't use Batch variables so it can be used on files of any size, although it is slower. I borrowed the method used by Andy Morris in its solution: 1- Insert line numbers in both files, 2- Combine both files in one, 3- Sort the combined file, and 4- Merge groups of lines into one same line. The program below is basically Andy's one with several small modifications that made it faster (with a subtle error fixed).

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

call :AddLineNumbers A1.txt A > Both.txt
call :AddLineNumbers A2.txt B >> Both.txt
sort Both.txt /O Sorted.txt
echo EOF: >> Sorted.txt
call :creatNewLines < Sorted.txt > Result.txt
goto :eof

:AddLineNumbers
findstr /n ^^ %1 > tem.tmp
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in (tem.tmp) do (
    set /a lineNo=1000000+%%a
    echo !lineNo!%2:%%b
)
goto :eof

:creatNewLines
set /p lineA1=
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ("%lineA1%") do (
    if %%a == EOF goto :eof
    set /p dummy=%%b< nul
)
set /p lineA2=
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ("%lineA2%") do echo  is from %%b
goto creatNewLines
```

SORT command order lines based on its contents. Andy's original method may fail because after the line number the lines are ordered based on line contents, so the lines of each file may be misplaced. In this method an additional character (A or B) is added after the line number, so the lines of each file are always placed in the right place.

Comment: Nice way of doing it, might get interesting with big files. From http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true, The maximum total environment variable size for all variables, which includes variable names and the equal sign, is 65,536KB. But probably way faster up to that limit

Comment: Good point about the ordering of lines for the sort. Not sure I bother to optimise, but you have some interesting techniques there.

Answer (score 1):

If your original data is in Data1.txt and Data2.txt this should do:

```
@echo off

    call :AddLineNumbers data1.txt Tem1.txt
    call :AddLineNumbers data2.txt Tem2.txt

    copy tem1.txt + tem2.txt tem3.txt 
    sort < tem3.txt > tem4.txt

    call :GetDataOut tem4.txt > tem5.txt

    set OddData=

    for /f %%a in (tem5.txt) do call :creatNewLines %%a

goto :eof



:AddLineNumbers

    find /v /n "xx!!xx" < %1 > tem.txt


    call :ProcessLines > %2


goto :eof

:ProcessLines

    for /f  "tokens=1,2 delims=[]"  %%a in (tem.txt) do call :EachLine %%a %%b 

goto :eof

:eachLine

    set LineNo=00000%1
    set data=%2 

    set LineNo=%LineNo:~-6%

    echo %LineNo% %data% 

goto :eof

:GetDataOut 
    for /f "tokens=2" %%a in (%1) do @echo %%a
goto :eof

:creatNewLines
    if "%oddData%"=="" (
        set oddData=%1
    ) else (
        echo %oddData% %1
        set oddData=
    )
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 0):

If using linux, I would recommend using cut and paste (command line).  See the man pages.

Alternatively, if you don't need the automation, you could use vim block mode cut and paste.  Enter block mode visual mode with control-v.