# How to merge two batch files using time delay?

Tags: java, batch-file

My Applications consist fo two parts:

1.First part is downloading the jars from the web server using java web start.Here i am using command promt ,once i fire command ,jars are getting downloaded.Jars are taking 15 min time to download.

2.Seccond Part ,Once the jars are getting downloaded ,i am removing some jars stating with name "RM" and deleting some "RT"named jars.In this i have applied some java code logic.

I have created separate batch files for both parts,but requirement tells that i want all in one batch file only,whether we can  merge these two files by adding some time delay in between ?

Plz help if its possible??

Comment: So I guess copying / pasting / **adapting** the commands from second batch at the bottom of first batch is hard to do?

Comment: Refer below link for your reference 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152861/batch-script-to-merge-lines-from-two-files-into-a-third-file

Thanks.

Comment: How can I merge two unknown scripts ?? Some questions are unblievable ...

Answer (score 0):

Try the below batch

---

@echo OFF

REM "Call your first batch"

@call "FirstBatch.bat"

REM "Delete RT and RM files here through magic"

REM "Add delay if u want. Here a delay of 5 second is added"

TIMEOUT /T 5

REM "Call your Second batch"

@call "SecondBatch.bat"

Comment: `timeout` is not included in XP.

Comment: yes. My bad. pinging localhost 5 times will add a delay 
'ping localhost -n 5'