# batch command merge csv rows

Tags: batch-file, cmd

My problem statement. I have 2 csv files. I want to merge first 2 rows of both files together become one.I run my code it seems like my second header is missing and the data append to 3rd row.

File A:

> ```
> A B 
> 1 2
> ```

File B:

> ```
> C D
> 3 4
> ```

Expected result:

> ```
> A B C D
> 1 2 3 4
> ```

My code:

```
@echo off
cd /d "C:\my csv directory"
set first=true
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(for %%x in (*.csv) do (
if !first!==true (
type "%%x"
echo.
set first=false
) ELSE (
more +1 "%%x"
)
))> c:\destination\newfile.csv
```

Fail result:

> ```
> a,b
> 1,2
> 3,4
> ```

Comment: Can you add the actual result made by your code?

Comment: my second file header are missing. It failed to merge into 2nd row

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch script to merge lines from two files into a third file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152861/batch-script-to-merge-lines-from-two-files-into-a-third-file)

Comment: solution from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152861/batch-script-to-merge-lines-from-two-files-into-a-third-file) is unable to replace file @aschipfl

Comment: Replace what? There is nothing to replace according to your question...

Answer (score 0):

To merge columns from two files you can read two files in paralllel

```
:: Merge2Files.cmd FileA FileB
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "FileA=FileA.txt"
Set "FileB=Fileb.txt"
<%FileB% (For /f "delims=" %%A in (%FileA%) Do (
    Set "B="&Set /P "B="
    Echo:%%A,!B!
)) >New-%FileA%
```