# Batch file - concatenate two .txt files to one

Tags: batch-file, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have some difficulties concatenating two text files.
First text file

```
Document1
Document2
Document3
```

Second text file

```
456
233
100
```

What I want to know is how to concatenate them in another text file so that so they can be seen this way

```
Document1-456
Document2-233
Document3-100
```

I have this code but it does not work as I want

```
@echo off
Set f1=file1.txt
set f2=file2.txt

FOR /F "Delims=" %%A in ('TYPE %f1%') DO (
    FOR /F "Delims=" %%B in ('TYPE %f2%') DO (
        echo.%%A-%%B >>newfile.txt
    )
)
```

I hope you can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45058064/batch-command-merge-csv-rows/45083711#45083711)

```
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "FileA=File1.txt"
Set "FileB=File2.txt"
<%FileB% (For /f "delims=" %%A in (%FileA%) Do (
    Set "B="&Set /P "B="
    Echo:%%A-!B!
)) >newfile.txt
```