# How to merge CSV files using batch file that adds to existing rows and columns?

Tags: file, csv, batch-file, join, merge

I need to merge the files side by side and not one under the other I have seen other examples and I have tried them but it does not seem to be working.

The file has two rows and 100 columns, Both files are this way:

```
copy "File1.csv" "File2.csv"
```

If I open the combined file in excel i am seeing the first row of the second file on the third row of the combined file. what i need is for the first row of both files to be combined sequentially, instead of one under the other.

Comment: While it is possible to do this with pure batch, it does have some caveats that may truncate your data.  It would better of you used the gnu implementation of the `PASTE` command as a third party solution.  Otherwise I would recommend doing this with Powershell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [batch-script-to-merge-lines-from-two-files-into-a-third-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152861/batch-script-to-merge-lines-from-two-files-into-a-third-file)

Comment: The problem that i have is both of those solutions i do not understand. all of the batch files i have implemented up to this point have been copies of solutions i have found else where. The possible duplicate one i wouldnt know where to start and i have read about powershell but i am not even sure what it is or how to use it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Please learn, [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Then it's time to learn. [SO] isn't a script writing service. Unless this is a recurring task cutting and pasting the rows/cols inside excel is done much faster.

Comment: It is a recurring task that needs to be repeated every day. I have no problem learning, finding a way to learn it is the problem. I am open to any suggestions

Comment: You should consider accepting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may need:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define variables for count of lines:
set /a F1=0
set /a F2=0

for /F "delims=" %%A IN (file1.csv) do (
    set /a F1+=1
    set F1[!F1!]=%%A
)

for /F "delims=" %%B IN (file2.csv) do (
    set /a F2+=1
    set F2[!F2!]=%%B
)

rem If the don't have, which is quite common, you can try:
if %F1% NEQ %F2% (
    if %F1% GTR %F2% (
        for /L %%C IN (1 1 %F1%) do (
            if %%C LSS %F2% (
                (echo/!F1[%%C]!,!F2[%%C]!)>>new.csv
            ) else (
                (echo/!F1[%%C]!)>>new.csv
            )
        )
    ) else (
        for /L %%C IN (1 1 %F2%) do (
            if %%C LSS %F1% (
                (echo/!F1[%%C]!,!F2[%%C]!)>>new.csv
            ) else (
                (echo/!F2[%%C]!)>>new.csv
            )
        )
    )
) else (
    for /L %%C IN (1 1 %F1%) do (
        (echo/!F1[%%C]!,!F2[%%C]!)>>new.csv
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Help message.
if "%~1" == "/?" goto :help

rem Set delimiter for joining lines.
if "%~3" == "" (set "delim=,") else set "delim=%~3"

rem Count the lines of the 1st file.
set "count=-1"
for /f "usebackq" %%A in ("%~1") do set /a "count+=1"

rem Merge the files.
for /l %%A in (0 1 %count%) do call :merge %%A %*
exit /b

:merge
if %~1 equ 0 (set "skip=") else set "skip=skip=%~1"

(
    for /f "usebackq %skip% delims=" %%A in ("%~2") do (
        set /p "=%%A" < nul
    ) & (
        for /f "usebackq %skip% delims=" %%B in ("%~3") do (
            set /p "=%delim%%%B" < nul
        ) & echo(& exit /b
    )
)
exit /b

:help
echo Merge lines of 2 text files.
echo(
echo Syntax: %~n0 file1 file2 [delimiter]
echo(
echo Examples:
echo   %~n0 a1.csv a2.csv
echo     Delimiter is comma (default).
echo   %~n0 a1.csv a2.csv ";"
echo     Delimiter is semi-colon.
echo   %~n0 a1.csv a2.csv ^> a3.csv
echo     Delimiter is comma (default).
echo     Redirect stdout to file a3.csv.
exit /b
```

This may do OK with 2 rows of a csv file though may be awful for
100's or 1000's of rows as it opens, reads a line and then closes the file.
The `skip` option means that when the file opens, it may need to count up
to the `skip` number which would slow down the read as each read line
number increases.

Due to the limits of CMD, a variable can store up to `4096` characters
so would allow up to average of `40` characters per cell between
delimiters, based on `100` cells per line.
If you get too near to `4096`. then the line line may truncate as
Squashman mentioned in a comment.

It does not support csv multi-line cells or
anything else exotic in the csv spec.
It is a dumb line merger using a delimiter to join.

It has a help message i.e.

```
scriptname /?
```

Or use it to merge 2 csv files:

```
scriptname file1.csv file2.csv
```

To save to output file, use:

```
scriptname file1.csv file2.csv > file3.csv
```

To set a delimiter other than `,`, use a 3rd argument.
`scriptname /?` shows an example.